# Can't Login to Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-10, boot-repair

I can't login to Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my Laptop. I also did the Boot-Repair, but ended up with an error. (http://paste.ubuntu.com/23594045/)

Appreciate if someone can help me overcome this issue.

Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "can't log in", be more specific. But if windows doesn't show up in the grub boot menu.. In your Ubuntu open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T at the same time). In the terminal type sudo update-grub. 
Reboot.